# Showing this random variable has normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose $\Omega = \mathbb{R}$. Take $\mathcal{B}$ the Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}$. Define $$P(A) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int 1_A(x) e^{- x^2/2} \mathrm{dx} $$

I have shown already that $P$ is a probability. Suppose $X : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is r.v given by $X(x) = x$. How can I show that $X$ has normal distribution with parameters $\mu = 0 $ and $\sigma^2 = 1 $ ?

Comment: I mean, don't you basically have it? I you want to be especially formal, let $A=(-\infty,x)$. Am I missing something?

Comment: probably is just trivial, but what I don't understand is what they mean when they say that we must show that $X$ has normal distribution: Does it mean that I need to find a density $f(x)$ ?

Comment: By definition, a random variable $X$ follows a (standard) normal distribution if $P(X\in A)=\int_A\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm{e}^{-x^2/2}\,\mathrm dx$ for all Borel sets $A$. Now you just have to argue that $P(X\in A)=P(A)$ which should be fairly obvious.